# (SQLITE_ERROR) SQL error or missing database (no such function: RAND) - Room Persistence Library

Tags: android, sql, database, kotlin, android-room

I have been facing issues while constructing a simple query to pull out 5 random albums from the device. All the audio files that are available on the device are stored in a table called song_table. The constructed query is as follows.

```
@Query("SELECT album_id, album_name, album_art, artist FROM song_table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5")
```

[image]

The error points out that there is no function called RAND that exists. Assuming that most of the SQL queries are supported with Room, is this a query that still does not have support? Or is there an alternative way to achieve this?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Replace `RAND()` by `RANDOM()`

Comment: @Yeray Thanks for this. Works perfectly :) It is a sham that Room's documentation doesn't have this.